# WriteToEventLog logging exceptions to the sql aspnet_db log file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, trace

Does anyone know about Writing to the Event Log in an aspnetdb_log file below is a snippit of code i found on the web with the original line of code but Log.LogException(..) doesn't work or i don't know the library to use so i used EventLog. What i want to do is log an error or event to the aspnetdb_log file will my code work i haven't tested it because I'm in the beginning stages if someone can make any corrections then please leave a reply thanks. This is for a custom membership provider

```
private void WriteToEventLog(Exception e, string action)
{
    string message = action + "-" + e.Message;

    if (!EventLog.SourceExists("aspnetdb_log"))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource("aspnetdb_log", "aspnetdb_log");
    }

    EventLog log = new EventLog();
    log.Source = "aspnetdb_log";
    log.WriteEntry(message, EventLogEntryType.Error);

    // original code doesn't work 
    // Log.LogException(message, e, LogCategory.Membership, TraceEventType.Error);  
}
```

Comment: why do you want to trace into this db only?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to find or write your own custom [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx) to write to database you want.

Then use [TraceSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.aspx) in your class, and configure both in Web.config.

Class:

```
public class SqlTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
private static TraceSource _traceSource = new TraceSource("MySource");

_traceSource.Trace(...);
```

Config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="MySource" />
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="sql" type="SqlTraceListener" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true">
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: @KDM: EventLog class will never write data to a database. TraceSource+TraceListener will.

Comment: Can they write top aspnetdb_log file or do they write to text files only

Comment: also how do you view aspnetdb_log file

Comment: @KDM: Your own listener can write wherever you want. Observe databases using SQL Management Studio or Server Explorer from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have administrative privileges to create an EventSource using CreateEventSource.

If the aspnetdb_log source already exists, I believe your code should run fine.

Comment: as you can understand db_log is a database and event log is what it is. in the rest you're correct

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a look at [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) it has has a number of different appenders allowing you to log to different locations ie database, eventlog as well as a textfile.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial) is quite a nice tutorial on using the different appenders